# Render links of these formats

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, markdown, external-links

I would like to have links like:

1. `[Google](google.com)` to render as `[Google](http://google.com)` and `[Google Drive](drive.google.com)` as `[Google Drive](http://drive.google.com)`
2. `[Google]s(google.com)` to render as `[Google](https://google.com)` and `[Google Drive]s(drive.google.com)` as `[Google Drive](https://drive.google.com)`

The `s` probably stands for 'secure'.

Comment: Why not? Is there already such a feature or an easier way?

Comment: You would need to explain why? The embed links 'feature' is markdown syntax for any link. Why have this special case for https? What if you actually want to type a plural with a link? Also as https is pretty much standardized, why support HTTP at all?

Comment: @SurajRao, if you want to type a plural, it'd be `[Google](google.com)s` -> `[Google](https://google.com)s`.

Comment: Can't you just put the http/https bit in the url? Why is additional syntax needed?

Comment: Just a shorter way, maybe?

Comment: Also, typing the colon and slashes in `http://` and `https://` is a pain.

Comment: I'm usually just copy-pasting links, any way...

Comment: @Cerbrus, what about sites like https://google.com? You type, not copy-paste them.

Comment: Note that [SE uses CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/241919) as the flavor, and it has [its defined specs](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/) such as [inline links](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#links).

Comment: If you are *really* opposed to including `http` you could do `[Google](//google.com)`; which'll take you to `https://google.com` (https because SO is https; `//`  means it would use the same protocol that you are using for the current site).

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder _when_ I actually type out an URL, I'm not that bothered by typing out `http(s)://`...

Comment: @Larnu, but what about `http`, then?

Comment: If you want http, you can type http

Comment: Imagine the amount of protocols you could've typed out instead of typing out this question and all these comments...

Comment: @Cerbrus, I know, but I just thought of something like this; don't know why.

Comment: You would have to put `http://`, @TheAmateurCoder , but not many sites aren't https any more (many reroute http to https)

Comment: Workaround: Let the browser expand it: Ctrl + T, Ctrl + V, Enter, F6, Ctrl + C (with `google.com` in the clipboard, replaced by `https://www.google.com/`). This was tested in Firefox.

Comment: I'd sort of like request #1 simply because it would mean that I could fit more links to sites other than the one I'm flagging on in a flag...or SE could just increase the max comment flag length like we've asked for for years ;-)  Then again, it'd really only buy you two characters per link due to protocol-relative URIs and the fact that basically every site supports HTTPS.  Overall, probably not worth the trouble.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking for here. Are you looking for specific special cases for `google.com` and `drive.google.com` because you type these a lot, or are you looking for Stack Overflow to deviate from how Markdown works **everywhere else in the world** and invent our own link syntax?

Comment: @user229044, the second, I guess.

Answer (score 6):

You're barking up the wrong tree.

We, nor the developers of Stack Overflow get to set or change the markdown specifications. You need to start at [Common Mark](https://commonmark.org). From  there you can find the [current Links spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#links).

You want to suggest a feature request against the Common Mark specification first and once that got accepted and released, you can ask here on Meta for the developers to upgrade their current markdown parser and renderer to the latest specs.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how HTML works.

The protocol is *required* because otherwise, the rendered HTML wouldn't know if the URL is relative or absolute.

Since the protocol is required any way, there's no point in writing:

`[Google]s(http://google.com)`

Instead of:

`[Google](https://google.com)`

Comment: Dang, minus 2. Are we forgetting that this MD is pretty naively parsed into HTML?

Comment: "It's done this way due to the way it is written" to a question literally asking for it to be changed is kinda weird. surely there's better reasoning than it works the way it works because that's how it works

Comment: This is more of a _"It's done this way because the way you're asking for can't work"_... The MD parser would have to _assume_ all urls are absolute. In SO's case, that's _probably_ right, but I wouldn't be surprised if there's at least _some_ relative urls out there.

Comment: it... can, though. markdown conversion to html is done with code, which very well could be changed to make it work the way they're requesting.. it'd just break a lot of existing links in the process while not adding any new functionality... all to save 4-5 keystrokes per link when most links are copy-pasted anyway.

Comment: @KevinB, No, as we cannot assume all urls are absolute.

Comment: that's not an unsolvable problem

Comment: That's _technically_ correct, but I don't think that invalidates my answer @KevinB :D

Comment: @KevinB, how would it "just break a lot of existing links in the process", LOL?

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder It may or may not break a lot of existing links. But you're changing the way *billions* of existing words are interpreted. It's not as simple as just introducing a new syntax, all existing text has to be vetted against this change. Regardless, it's not a suggestion that anybody seriously thinks will go ahead. It doesn't solve a real problem that anybody has, at the cost of producing a custom markdown implementation that is not compatible with the rest of the world.